# Compiler and CPU reordering

Tags: c++, winapi, compiler-optimization, memory-barriers

I have this following situation.

```
volatile double val1 = 10.0;
volatile double val2 = 20.0;

double SetValues(double d1, double d2)
{
  double ret = d1-d2;
  InterlockedExchange64( (volatile long long*)&val1, *((long long*)&d1) ); // val1 = d1;
  InterlockedExchange64( (volatile long long*)&val2, *((long long*)&d2) ); // val2 = d2;
  return val1 - va2;
}
```

My question is, is it possible that either CPU or the compiler reorders the lines of `SetValues()` function?

Comment: there is a clear dependency of line 2 and 3 from line 1, how this can ever be reordered?

Comment: @Andrey: I do not know. That is what I am asking.

Comment: Why are you using `volatile`? And why don't you just put it inside a critical section?

Comment: `val1` won't get the value of `d1`, it will get the bit pattern of `d1` converted to `long long`. You want `*(long long*)&d1`.

Comment: No, it won't reorder the memory accesses in your case. But this looks like *ridiculous* overkill. Do you need every line to be interlocked, and do you need all the variables to be volatile? It looks like you have no clue how to do achieve thread safety, and are just throwing everything and the kitchen sink at the problem, hoping that'll work. (I realize that this is just example code, and it might not reflect how you'd actually solve such problems in reality)

Comment: Further to David Hefferman's comment: If you want to make sure that `delta` is calculated correctly, you *have to* put this into a critical section. Otherwise some other thread's going to come along and modify `val1` or `val2` after you do, but before you calculate `delta`.

Comment: @David Haffernan, @Jim Mischel: Do not wory. I use critical section in actual implementation. Besides this code is useless, thanks to @aaz `&(val1 - val2)` is invalid. It is just not a well prepared question. My apologies.

Comment: If you use a critical section then what's this question about? Sheesh!

Comment: @jalf: Why on earth do you think I am doing this to ensure thread-safety? I do not even use the word "thread".

Comment: @sad_man: because outside of thread safety, reordering of memory accesses generaly doesn't matter. (Unless you're doing memory-mapped I/O, in which case `volatile` would have been sufficient without the `Interlocked` ops. Are you saying that you're jumping through hoops to prevent an optimization that you don't need to prevent? I'm just pointing out that for practical purposes, code such as this is needlessly complex and needlessly inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler can never reorder calls to functions in external libraries.  If your compiler implements these functions as intrinsics, it will be smart enough not to reorder them.

As far as CPU reordering is concerned, [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683593.aspx) says "This function generates a full memory barrier (or fence) to ensure that memory operations are completed in order."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This sentence is the actual reason that I ask that question. Sadly I could not ask it properly due to lack of time. So interlocked opereations provide memory barriers but do these barriers prevent the reordering of the lines of interlocked ops. or the whole scope that interlocked ops. lie within?

Comment: A memory fence affects all memory operations submitted by that core.  The interlocked operation may happen before or after other operations that have been requested, but the barrier assures that all those operations, including the interlocked exchange, are flushed before the function returns.